# Fading action of SKNode() with SKCropNode() children

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I have a SKNode() which has SKCropNode() children. I am able to run all kind of actions to rotate and scale my SKNode(), but when I want to use any kind of fading actions the result always is alpha 1 or alpha 0. No way of fading.

By replacing the SKCropNode() with a SKShapeNode() the fading action is working fine.

Can anyone tell my why? Isn't it possible to fade masked nodes?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let player = SKNode()
let playerSize = CGFloat(50)
let playerCrop = SKCropNode()
let playerMask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(100), CGFloat(100)))
let playerCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(100))

let playerCenterMask = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(100))
let playerCenterCrop = SKCropNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    player.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    player.alpha = 0
    addChild(player)

    playerCenterMask.lineWidth = 20        
    playerCenterCrop.maskNode = playerCenterMask

    playerMask.position.x = -playerSize
    playerMask.position.y = playerSize
    playerCircle.lineWidth = 0
    playerCircle.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    playerCrop.addChild(playerCircle)
    playerCrop.maskNode = playerMask

    playerCenterCrop.addChild(playerCrop)
    player.addChild(playerCenterCrop)

    // Animations
    let playerScale = SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 5)
    let playerFadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(5)
    let playerAnimation = SKAction.group([playerScale,playerFadeIn])

    player.runAction(playerAnimation, completion: {})

}

}
```

Comment: can you post your code so i can try it

Comment: Thank you, I have added some example code :)

Comment: try setting the mask to clear color, not black,  the alpha has a value of 1, so you are saying crop all alpha

Comment: thx for your help. setting the mask to clearcolor only results in not masking anymore.

Comment: then you want the opposite, all white for anything masked and clear for anything not masked

Comment: I always get it backwards,the way masking works it does a XOR of source and destination

Comment: But the masking is not the problem :) The masking is working fine. I you c&p the code, you will see what I mean. 

SKAction.fadeInWithDuration() is not working when children have masks :(

Comment: I am playing with your code now,  it works when the mask nodes are nil, which means the masks are the issue

Comment: hmm,  I just looked it up, man was it buried,  apparently cropnode uses alpha < 0.5 to not draw. >= 0.5 to draw, and I can't set the  blend mode, so it is probably doing source blend mode.  Which means it could me overwriting the alpha, since I applied alpha change to the child and it worked.  So player context is created, it draws at the given alpha,  then the crop node is draw, overwriting alpha not blending, then children are blended

Comment: Run the fade in action on your child, not your parent to get the results you are looking for,  tested and works (remember to set alpha to 0 on child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:
`SKCropNode` uses alpha < 0.5 to not draw. >= 0.5 to draw, and you can't set the blend mode, so it is probably doing source blend mode. Which means it is overwriting the alpha. Children afterwards get blended.

The player context is created, it draws at the given alpha, then the `SKCropNode` is drawn, overwriting alpha instead of blending.

Run the fade in action on your child, not your parent to get the results you are looking for.

Here is what your source looks like with changes:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKNode()
    let playerSize = CGFloat(50)
    let playerCrop = SKCropNode()
    let playerMask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(100), CGFloat(100)))
    let playerCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(100))

    let playerCenterMask = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(100))
    let playerCenterCrop = SKCropNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

        player.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        player.alpha = 1
        addChild(player)
        playerCircle.alpha = 0
        playerCenterMask.lineWidth = 20
        playerCenterCrop.maskNode = playerCenterMask

        playerMask.position.x = -playerSize
        playerMask.position.y = playerSize
        playerCircle.lineWidth = 0
        playerCircle.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
        playerCrop.addChild(playerCircle)
        playerCrop.maskNode = playerMask
        playerCenterCrop.addChild(playerCrop)
        player.addChild(playerCenterCrop)

        // Animations
        let playerScale = SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 5)
        let playerFadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(5)
        let playerAnimation = playerScale

        player.runAction(playerAnimation, completion: {})
        playerCircle.runAction(playerFadeIn, completion: {})

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It is definetly the result I am looking for! You saved me!